Finding formulas for molar internal energy and molar enthalpy of mixing fluids
There is a Y-shaped pipe connection. One fluid flows through one pipe with molar flow $\nu_1$, molar internal energy $U_1$, molar enthalpy $H_1$; through the second pipe - another fluid with molar flow $\nu_2$, molar internal energy $U_2$, molar enthalpy $H_2$; a mixture with molar flow $\nu=\nu_1+\nu_2$, molar internal energy $U$, molar enthalpy $H$ comes out of the third pipe. Additional conditions: the flows are stationary, the gravitational and kinetic energy of the fluids as a whole can be neglected, the system is thermally insulated, no chemical reactions occur between the fluids. Question: What are the general formulas for $U$ and $H$? Please, if possible, with reference to the literature.
Details. The question is what exactly needs to be mixed here, internal energy $U=(\nu_1U_1+\nu_2U_2)/\nu$ or enthalpy $H=(\nu_1H_1+\nu_2H_2)/\nu$? Both cannot be true; this can be shown in a particular example. Let all fluids be ideal gases, $U=c_vT$, $H=c_pT$, the first monatomic, $c_{v1}=3R/2$, $c_{p1}=5R/2$, the second diatomic, $c_{v2}=5R/2$, $c_{p2}=7R/2$. In this case, if $U$ is mixed, then one can get the formula for the output temperature $T=(\nu_1 3 T_1+\nu_2 5 T_2)/(\nu_1 3+\nu_2 5)$. If $H$ is mixed, then $T=(\nu_1 5 T_1+\nu_2 7 T_2)/(\nu_1 5+\nu_2 7)$. These formulas are obviously different. I assume that in this particular case the $U$-formula is correct, this follows from the additivity of kinetic and rotational energies of molecules and the calculation of the total number of degrees of freedom. The question: is the formula $U=(\nu_1U_1+\nu_2U_2)/\nu$ correct in the general case, for real gases and liquids, with the possible presence of phase transitions?
UPD: After reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics#First_law_of_thermodynamics_for_open_systems . Still unclear, Eq.(3) $\Delta U_0=Q-W-\sum\Delta U_i$ and Eq.(5) $dU_0=\delta Q-\delta W+\sum h_i dN_i$. I suspect $\Delta U_0=dU_0=0$ for steady state, $Q=\delta Q=0$ due to insulation. I'm not sure whether any total work is done by the system, there are just pipes, there are also equal pressures, but may be different volume flows at inlets and outlet. If no work is done, $W=\delta W=0$, then one formula says $\sum\Delta U_i=0$, the other $\sum h_i dN_i=0$. One says that the total internal energy is preserved, the other -- that the total enthalpy is preserved. Only one of these statements can be correct.
UPD2: Thanks for the comments. After reading the above wiki, and contrary to what was written earlier, I am now of the opinion that the $H$-formula is the correct one. Let's consider the node in which mixing occurs as a small-volume ball. It contains a mixture at a pressure $P$, and the same pressure is present in three adjacent pipes. Indeed, a pressure jump at the junction would result in a non-zero force acting on the small volume entering or leaving the pipe. Due to the small mass of the volume, it would have an unlimitedly large acceleration. Therefore, the pressures at the inlets and outlets are equal. Also, turbulent or laminar friction forces act on long pipe segments. Here we consider short segments adjacent to the node and neglect friction forces.
Next, the internal energy $\nu_1U_1$ from one pipe enters the node. Also, importantly, the system performs negative work $-PV_1$ against the pressure force, $V_1=\nu_1\mu_1/\rho_1$, where $\mu_1/\rho_1$ represents the molar volume. Likewise for the other input and output. The total formula is $\nu_1U_1 + P \nu_1 \mu_1/\rho_1+ \nu_2U_2 + P \nu_2 \mu_2/\rho_2 = \nu U + P \nu \mu/\rho$, combining into $\nu_1 H_1 + \nu_2 H_2 = \nu H$. Therefore, the enthalpies are mixed, not internal energies. However, if the problem were nonstationary, apparently, the formula $\nu_1 H_1 + \nu_2 H_2 - \nu H = d(V (\rho/\mu) U)/dt$ would be correct, the total enthalpy flow is on the left, and the change in total internal energy in the node is on the right.
I would be grateful if these formulas would be confirmed by a reference to the literature. I have written them here from common sense, and I am not sure that I have taken into account all the factors.

Is the system at steady state?  Are the inlet and outlet pressures all the same?  Are you familiar with the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics?  Are the pipes insulated?

Yes, the system is at steady state, the pipes are insulated, pressures are the same at the pipes in immediate contact to their junction. Thank you for the reference, I looked into wiki and added more info to the post.

Then from the open system version of the first law of thermodynamics, $vh=(v_1h_1+v_2h_2)$
